# WHERE on JOINed table - only apply if rows are found (joined)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My query:

```
SELECT
    T1.* 
FROM
    table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.fk = T1.id
WHERE
    T2.active = 1
```

Not all rows from `table1` can be joined to `table2`. For those that can, `T2.active=1` constraint should be set.

**Question**:

How can I fix that query for the case when no joined rows can be found in `table2`, but I'd still get row from `table1` (sort of, `IF EXISTS, then T2.active=1`)

Thanks!

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Your task looks like extremely strange. Now (after solving your issue) it is "for each record from table `t1`, return as many duplicates of it as there are related records in `t2`, and one if there is no related record". Maybe you need some columns from table `t2` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition on the second table should be in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM table1 T1 LEFT JOIN 
     table2 T2
     ON T2.fk = T1.id AND T2.active = 1;
```

Note that if you are just selecting columns from `table1` this is not particularly important.  I assume your `SELECT` actually has columns from both tables.